# Resizing Multiple Shapes but Keeping Aspect Ration in JFrame

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to make a ship which can resize itself by pressing a key. I have that working the only problem is how do I get the two ovals to increase or decrease in size but stay in relation to each other? Currently as they get much smaller or bigger they lose the original shape. I'm not sure if there is a way to lock the ration between multiple shapes in a `JFrame` or not, I'm not able to find anything on Oracle or Google.

```
    public void paint (Graphics g) {
        g.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        g.fillRect(0, 0, xMax, yMax);
        g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        g.fillOval(x,y,widthBody,heightBody);
        g.fillOval(x+11, y-10, widthTop, heightTop);
    }

    public void keyPressed( KeyEvent e ) {
        int keyPressed = e.getKeyCode();
        switch(keyPressed) {
            case KeyEvent.VK_UP:
                y-=10;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_DOWN:
                y+=10;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_LEFT:
                x-=10;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT:
                x+=10;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_B:
                widthBody = widthBody-10;
                heightBody = heightBody-5;
                widthTop = widthTop-10;
                heightTop = heightTop-5;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;
            case KeyEvent.VK_S:
                widthBody = widthBody+10;
                heightBody = heightBody+5;
                widthTop = widthTop+10;
                heightTop = heightTop+5;
                repaint();
                e.consume();
                break;  
        }
    }
```

The b and s keys resize the ovals so that their ration between height and width remain at 2X, but when I run this, as it gets smaller the top oval will begin to lift above the bottom oval.

I don't quite understand how the ovals are drawn in respect to the given x or y coordinates.

Comment: Maintain a scale factor, instead of an absolute value.  Increase and decrease the scaling factor and then apply this to the shapes.  This means that the shape(s) must have a concept of a default (scale factor 1) size

Comment: 1) I'd tend to create a single `Shape` of both geometric primitives, then it can be translated, scaled or rotated at will. 2) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 0):

> how do I get the two ovals to increase or decrease in size but stay in relation to each other?

```
g.fillOval(x+11, y-10, widthTop, heightTop);
```

Well you can't hard code values like "11" and "10". The distance between the two will be based on the size of each.

So I would guess you should be using widthBody and heightBody?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks. It makes sense that the distance between shapes should be relative to their size not a hard coded factor.

I eventually quit trying to figure out the relation between coordinates and size and found Graphics2D, which has a scaling method that did the work for me. It would probably still take me forever to figure out the equations and parameters for it to scale properly.

Thanks all